# create sqlite view in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am taking data from two tables with cursors and it's taking too much time, what i'am trying to achive for a certain key(KEY_pk_ymd) from the table A i get ids(id1{;}id2{;}...)- column and for those ids

```
 do
{
 ...something
}
while(rowGetter.moveToNext());
```

i get each of them and then call a second cursor that uses the specific ID and gets different column for that id from table B , so because is so slow i want to make some sort of a view if it's possible to speed up the process here is what i have the structure of the tables...

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
        + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_title_ids + " text, "         
        + KEY_pk_ymd + " integer);";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " ("
        + KEY_ROWIDz + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_title_id + " integer, "
        + KEY_desc + " text ");";
```

is there a faster way of doing this maybe ???

Comment: probably a join, but without your queries it is hard to tell.

Comment: Joins and possibly indexes on the tables will likely help, but without the actual queries it's hard to say.

Comment: well how do i join when i have to join by id od table B and a list of ids (id1{;}id2{;}id3{;}) on table A

Answer (score 0):

You need a table join, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
b.title_id,
b.desc
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
   ON b._id = a._id
WHERE a.pk_ymd = ?
```

You can then run that as a parameterised query where you supply the value to map to the ?, e.g.:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {pk_ymd_value} );
```

That is then one call to the database compared to your current approach which opens multiple cursors.